# How do I use a hashmap iterator to print more than one entryKey in Android?

Tags: android, iterator, hashmap

I have a hashmap and an iterator that iterates through four alternatives and the corresponding value to a question. I have a TableLyaout where a TableRow is added programmatically depending on how many rows there are. 
I get it to print a random alternative, but only the one. How can I get all four alternatives to get written in a textview each?

```
 Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
             while (entries.hasNext()) {
               Entry<String, Integer> entry = entries.next();
               String alternative = entry.getKey();
               Integer value = entry.getValue();

            try { 
                    alternative = new String(alternative.getBytes("macintosh"), "UTF-8");} 
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            mTvAlt.setText(alternative +" "+value);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
        arrayAlternative = map.keySet().toArray();
        arrayValue = map.values().toArray();       

       Object [] alternative = arrayAlternative[x].toString();
       Object [] value = arrayValue[x].toString();
```

I would have preferred to get the value as an integer array, but didn't know how so I took it as a string array.